# Rails 4: What object types can a session hold?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know it's frowned upon to store ActiveRecord model objects in the session, but a session can do more than hold a string and an integer, so I want to know how complex it can get before things start getting messy.

If you store an ActiveRecord model object and it changes, things explode. What if I store an array of hashes? I have this:

```
session[:tray] ||= Array.new
@tray = session[:tray]
```

and I am currently storing hashes like this:

```
  tray_item = {'product_name' => product.name, 
    'products_color_id' => products_color.id, 
    'product_images' => products_color.product_images.map(&:image).map(&:url),
    'section' => params[:section]
  }
  @tray << tray_item
```

So basically it's just an array of hashes with strings as keys and strings/integers as values. Is this at all frowned upon? How are session variables stored? In Ruby?

Comment: Do not store large objects in a session. Instead you should store them in the database and save their id in the session. This will eliminate synchronization headaches and it won't fill up your session storage space (depending on what session storage you chose, see below). This will also be a good idea, if you modify the structure of an object and old versions of it are still in some user's cookies. With server-side session storages you can clear out the sessions, but with client-side storages, this is hard to mitigate. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-guidelines

Comment: Kinda a broad stroke type of comment, but valid nonetheless. Session is just a magical semi-persistent serialized storage mechanism. Yes, keep your session storage slim, always a good idea. Although I do some Ruby/RoR, my experience on sessions is from other languages. The use will indeed blow up, when or how is hard to say as the server and config is part of the equation, just like size of data and storage mechanism (DB session or not for example) should be considered. Bottom line : rethink what you are doing and/or approach it differently. @Edmund points out valid thoughts on this as well.

Comment: @datamafia Just quoting the Rails guides, and as you say I think the op needs to rethink a bit the role of sessions. Caching is something that looks more suitable for this situation.

Comment: Well I'm actually saving this only temporarily and based on the session (the `@tray` won't persist after the user closes the browser), which is why I decided not to make a table for this

Comment: @Iceman something that RoR people often forget - the same tools/infrastructure used for these languages. Caching is a solid idea. I also like the idea of dropping the obj/data in DB w/key stored in cookie/session. Then I would drink a bunch of coffee and write a job to clear out data every (?) 4 hours. Rails can quickly solicit devs into a dark alley to get beat up, other language and sysadmin exp very helpful to not get burned.

Comment: @Edmund if the `@tray` won’t persist after the user closes the browser, you may as well just save it with JavaScript at browser. No need to hit server at all in this case.